# How to retrieve image using WCF service in Android

Tags: android, wcf

I'm getting null value in Bitmap decode stream when I try to read values from JSONobject. I do not know where I made mistake. Please try to find my mistake or give alternate solution for my problem. In JSONObject string I am getting the value!.. In DB image value is getting stored as image type and receiving as byte[] in WCF. For more please check the below code.

Android Code:

```
     protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        empID=params[0];
        sendUrl="http://192.168.1.11:5252/RestServiceImpl.svc/signed?empid="+empID;
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(sendUrl);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpRequest);

            BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line + NL);

            }

            inStream.close();
            String result = buffer.toString();  
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
            //String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("EmployeeID").getString("pageName");

            Iterator<?> keys = obj.keys();

            while( keys.hasNext() ){
                String key = (String)keys.next();
                Object jsonEntity= obj.get(key);
                String SignatureLink= jsonEntity.toString();
                String newString = SignatureLink.replace("data:image/png;base64,","");                  
                //byte[] image= jsonEntity.toString().getBytes();               
                InputStream stream = new     ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(newString.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));

                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);// Getting Null Value

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                //imageView.refreshDrawableState();
                return bitmap;
        } 
        }
            catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            return null;
        }

        return null;            
    }
```

WCF Interface:

```
      [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        UriTemplate = "/signed?empid={empid}")]
    byte[] signedornot(string empid);
```

WCF Implementation:

```
   public byte[] signedornot(string empid) {



        DataSet EmpID = db.ExecuteDataset("select Signature from emp_tb_eob_Employee where EmployeeID=" + Convert.ToInt32( empid));
        byte[] signature= (byte[])EmpID.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Signature"];
        if (signature == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else {
            return signature;
        }
```

Comment: Start with adding Log.d() statements where you log the content of `SignatureLink` and `newString` to see if indeed the right content with a nice base64 string is there.

Comment: And you are replacing a string with a "," where i would think that "" would be appropiate as a base64 encoded string will not contain a comma as first character. If you add e.printStackTrace() to the catch block and also log e.getMessage() you will see much more.

Comment: Thank you.. So much .. Greenapps.. I will check it..